# Does expressjs automatically generate a new session id?

Tags: express

So I'm creating an express application and I'm using express-session. I'm new to express so I will clarify anything if needed.

I was reading a medium article and came across this:

> Genid - A function to generate a new session ID. The default value is a function that uses the uid-safe library to generate IDs.

I'm using express-session so do I need to generate IDs for each user or does express-session do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express-session` will automatically generate a session ID for you.   If you have a specific reason to want to generate your own ID instead of using theirs, you can replace their session ID generation with your own, but you do not have to.

> I'm using express-session so do I need to generate IDs for each user

No, you do not need to do it yourself.

> or does express-session do it for me?

Yes, it does it for you.